# Capture phase dominating bubble phase

Tags: javascript

I am learning about JavaScript event bubbling and capturing phases.While doing so i ran into a problem.Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <body>    
        <p id="para">Learning <span id="span"><b>events</b></span></p>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("para").addEventListener("click",function(){
                                                          alert("Paragraph was clicked");
                                                               },true);
             document.getElementById("span").addEventListener("click",function(){
                                                          alert("Span was clicked");
                                                               },false);                                                 
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is when i click on the **span** element, the alert on the **paragraph** element fires first followed by the alert on **span**.I think it's probably because of the capture phase which i had set on the paragraph element.My question is about the reason.Why is it doing so?? According to the definition,it should fire the event on span first followed by the event on paragraph.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is because you have explicitly set the event on the `<p>` tag to execute on the capturing phase.

And since the capturing phase occurs first, this event handler executes first.

And since you have set the event listener on the `span` to execute in the bubbling phase (by supplying false in the third argument), it executes after the handler for paragraph tag.

Here is a good explanation of how the [capturing phase](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#capturing) works.

Comment: if explanation answers your question, would appreciate if you could accept the answer.